# Django-CMS custom plugin not showing data in published pages

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-cms

I created a custom plugin for my project in Django/Django-CMS and the plugin has a list of testimonials that the user pick when adding the plugin to the page. The model is this:

```
class TestimonialsPlugin(CMSPlugin):
    n_testimonials = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name=_('Number of Testimonials'), default=5)

    speed_autoplay = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name=_('Speed of slider (milliseconds)'), default=3000)

    picked_testimonials = models.ManyToManyField(Testimonials,
                                                 verbose_name=_('picked_testimonials'),
                                                 blank=True, null=True)
```

In the edit mode I can se the testimonials in my page and I can publish without errors but when I see the published page the testimonials doesn't show. The plugin template is being rendered but the picked_testimonials gives `None`. Here's the template:

```
<div class="max-width1440 block clearfix relative">
    <div class="small-only-text-left small-12 small-offset-0 medium-text-center medium-offset-1 medium-10 large-offset-1 large-10 column pt-px60 pb-px40 pl-px40 pr-px40 slider-testimonials">
        {% for testimonial in instance.picked_testimonials.all %}
            {% if forloop.counter0 < instance.n_testimonials %}
                <div class="slider column">
                    <blockquote class="acta_mediumitalic size36 pl-px80 pr-px80 line-height140">
                        {% render_model testimonial "description" %}
                    </blockquote>

                    <div class="mt-px30">
                        <p class="acta_book size20 softblack">{{ testimonial.author }},<span>{{ testimonial.city }}</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a page is published, a copy of a plugin is created - which does include plugin's fields but not any relations. There is a provision in the CMS to provide copy method for exactly this purpose, see example from [documentation](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/how_to/custom_plugins.html):

```
class ArticlePluginModel(CMSPlugin):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sections = models.ManyToManyField(Section)

    def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
        self.sections = oldinstance.sections.all()
```

The important bit is the copy_relations, which ensures that the new object has the same relational links.

In your case, something along these lines should work:

```
class TestimonialsPlugin(CMSPlugin):
    n_testimonials = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name=_('Number of Testimonials'), default=5)

    speed_autoplay = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name=_('Speed of slider (milliseconds)'), default=3000)

    picked_testimonials = models.ManyToManyField(Testimonials,
                                                 verbose_name=_('picked_testimonials'),
                                                 blank=True, null=True)

    def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
        self.picked_testimonials = oldinstance.picked_testimonials.all()
```

Comment: Glad I could help and enjoy working with Django CMS!